# D3.js: What is the (current) standard way of using force layout?

Tags: d3.js, idioms

Force layout on a graph can be implemented by the following steps:

Binding the graph to the force layout:

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
  .gravity(.03)
  .charge(-400)
  .distance(150)
  .nodes(data.nodes)
  .links(data.links)
  .size([600, 400]);
```

Defining a tick function for the simulation steps:

```
force.on("tick", function(e) {
  vis.selectAll("circle")
  .attr("px", function(d) { return d.x; })
  .attr("py", function(d) { return d.y; });
  ...
```

Starting, running and stopping the force:

```
force.start();
for (var i = 0; i > 1000; i++) force.tick();
force.stop();
```

However, according to the documentation (https://github.com/d3/d3-force) force is used with `d3.forceSimulation`, `simulation.tick()`, `simulation.nodes` etc.

Is my way of force usage deprecated?

If so, what is the preferred standard way of doing it? How does my example look like according to the standard?

Comment: Yes, deprecated.  New version **4.0** not backwards compatible.  New version **4.0** even better then 3.0...

Answer (score 0):

The `d3.forceSimulation` is the new way on D3 4.0. The `d3.layout.force` is the method for D3 3.x.

Comment: And how would my code example translate into the new way?